# Multi-branch diff with git?

Tags: git, branch, diff

Is there an easy way to get the diff between multiple (more than two) branches with git? (Something like an "octopus diff"?)

The situation is that there is a branch (call it branch A) which is the result of a merge of multiple other branches (call them B and C) along with other modifications. (Branch A diverged from branch B, had a number of local modifications, then branch C was merged in, followed by more local modifications, then even more local modifications and re-merging to include updates on the B and C branches.)

What I'd like to do is see all local changes unique to branch A - that is, see what changes have been made to branch A that aren't on either branch B or branch C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a branch "bPlusC" off of B, and then merge "C". Diff that with "A".

```
git checkout -b bPlusC B
git merge --no-ff C
git checkout A
git diff bPlusC..HEAD
```

**EDIT:** Based on R.M.'s comment:

If B or C have commits that are not in A use this:

```
git checkout -b bPlusC $(git merge-base A B)
git merge --no-ff $(git merge-base A C)
git checkout A
git diff bPlusC..HEAD
```

Comment: That works only if B and C are completely merged into A. If those branches have commits not yet merged into A, those will show up as an inverse change on the diff. To correct for that, I think git merge-base should help: `git checkout -b bPlusC B $(git merge-base A B)` and `git merge --no-ff $(git merge-base A C)` (Though do you really need the --no-ff?)

Comment: @R.M. I changed the answer. `--no-ff` is not strictly necessary, but it leaves more of a visible trail. Since you will not be pushing this branch (I hope), I am not so concerned about making an "ugly" merge.

Comment: Slight addition/correction: depending on how complicated your merge pattern is, there might be *multiple* merge-bases, but only one is output by default. The flag "--all" will get them all, but the protocol changes slightly. A `git merge-base --all A B C` should(?) find the SHA1 of the relevant commits (the A branch must come first, then two or more negative branches). If only one, congratulations, just use that as the diff reference. If multiple, then use the new-branch + merge strategy with the listed SHA1s, as opposed to the B & C commits or the command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting an option which doesn't completely answer my question, but which I puzzled out during my research.)*

One possibility is to use the -p (patch) option of `git log`, which can take multiple branch labels for both inclusion and exclusion:

```
git log -p branch_A ^branch_B ^branch_C
```

This doesn't give a single summary of changes like git diff would, though, instead giving the separate changes for each commit included in branch A but not in branches B or C.

While less than ideal for getting an overall picture of the changes introduced by branch A, this commit-by-commit summary might be more useful when you're trying to cherry-pick changes from branch A.